# Yes/No If $R$ be a ring with unit such that $a^2=a$ for $a \in R.$ Then$ R=\{0,1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the following statement true/false ?

If $R$  be  a ring with unit  such that $a^2=a$ for $a \in R.$ Then $ R=\{0,1\}$

**My attempt** : I think this statement is  true

$(a+a)^2=a +a$

$(a+a)(a+a)=a+a \implies a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2=a+a \implies a+a+a+a=a+a$

$\implies a+a=0$ by cancellation laws

Therefore $a=-a  \implies  2a=0$ and $R=\mathbb{Z_2}$ i,e $R=\{0,1\}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring

Comment: @EmilJeřábek  It's true, am I right?

Comment: No jasmine, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#Examples

Comment: $2R=\{0\}$ does not imply $R=\Bbb Z_2.$ $R$ may be huge.

Comment: okay @AnneBauval   In other words,  $R=(P(S);\triangle)$ where where $P(S)$  is the power set of $S$.Am i right ?

Comment: @AnneBauval  where $A \triangle B =(A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$

Comment: Come on jasmine, again: read the link to Wikipedia more carefully, especially that paragraph "Examples" and in that paragraph, the first example (duplicated in the accepted answer below). Note that you need two operations for a ring, not just one.

Comment: In addition to the first comments, which already completely answered your question(s), please look at [Understanding boolean rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297016) and/or [Ring structure on power set of a set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953952). I think your post should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: okay@AnneBauval

Comment: For example, $F_2\times F_2$ ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a set X.
Now consider its power set.

Now consider the operation on the power set to be:

- Symmetric Difference as "addition"
- Intersection as "multiplication"

In this structure, the "square" of any element is itself.

Check that all conditions for a ring hold.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate (see links above).

Answer (score 0):

Posting this Answer because the other Answer ( which is valid ! ) & the Online Examples & the Comments are mostly about Power Sets & Sub-Sets , while I wanted to give a much simpler Example.

Let the ring have all n-bit Binary Strings Eg when $n=8$ , the Elements are $\{00000000,00000001,00000010,\cdots,11111110,11111111\}$ ( 256 Elements ! )

Let ADDITION $+$ be bit-wise "EXCLUSIVE-OR".
Let MULTIPLICATION $\times$ be bit-wise "AND".

We can see that $a + a = 2a = 00000000$ ( always , no matter which Binary String $a$ is )
We can also see $a \times a = a^2 = a$ ( always , no matter which Binary String $a$ is )

Hence , we can have a "large ring" with arbitrary size , not just 2 Elements $\{0,1\}$.
More-over , there is no necessity to consider just Power Sets & Sub-Sets.
There are other "types" of Examples too.

Comment: This is like the other answer, in a different guise, i.e., you example of a ring of $n$-element bits is an encoding of a power-set on an $n$-element set $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ where each subset in encoded as a sequence of bits having $1$ in the $k$-th position iff the $x_k$ belongs to that subset. The operations coincide too. (+1) since this might be easier to understand to some.

Comment: However, this answer is a multiduplicate. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398323), and all those linked or related to it.

Comment: Yes , I realized that Connection , when I was typing $256=2^8$ , @amrsa , & I thought about eliminating a few elements to make it not Isomorphic to the Power Set , though I eventually decided that it would then become unintuitive & cumbersome , hence I left it as-it-was !! Mean-while , I **think** I have cooked up a new valid Example which may not be easily Connected to the Power Set Way , but I think I should not update my Answer , this Question being a Multi-Duplicate !!